# Javascript ES6 best practice, variable instantiation

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, reactjs

I have a question about best practices that I just read from:
https://github.com/ryanmcdermott/clean-code-javascript#remove-duplicate-code

The question is about variable assignment

```
      let portfolio = employee.getGithubLink();

      if (employee.type === 'manager') {
        portfolio = employee.getMBAProjects();
      }
```

My way of doing this in order to instantiate portfolio only 1 time.

```
      if (employee.type === 'manager') {
        let portfolio = employee.getMBAProjects();
      } else {
        let portfolio = employee.getGithubLink();
      }
```

My question is: Why is it preferable to instantiate a variable and overwrite it than just instantiate it one time with the "else" statement.

Comment: Because with your way, if the `type` isn't 'manager', the `portfolio` variable won't exist, and conditionally creating variables is often a bad idea. What happens if you try to use `portfolio` down the script when the type wasn't manager?

Comment: I think it really depends on the situation, and how you will use that variable, to be honest. Having/using variables that potentially could be undefined is a terrible idea though.

Comment: Sorry @Carcigenicate I did a mistake I edited it !

Comment: Rhetorical question: how expensive is that call to .getGithubLink()? A ternary operator would avoid the potential of making 2 calls. Or declare it = null, then do the if/else assignment.

Comment: @AlexyHody Ahh. In your new example though, I don't think that would work. Doesn't `let` limit the scope to the enclosing block? Ignoring that, I think any difference between the 2 is more subjective than anything. Ternary would probably be the way to go, providing you know there will only ever be 2 options.

Answer (score 1):

I'd consider

```
const portfolio = (employee.type === 'manager') ? employee.getMBAProjects() : employee.getGithubLink();
```

as an option. You should not overwrite / mutate variables without a proper reason.

Comment: Oh yeah ternaries ! Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

**First of all**, if you define variable with `let`, it will available only inside a block scope where it was defined (inside `{` `}`). So if doing it your way, variable `portfolio` will be `undefined` outside condition statement. In this option you could use `var` keyword and it would work

```
if (employee.type === 'manager') {
  var portfolio = employee.getMBAProjects();
} else {
  var portfolio = employee.getGithubLink();
}
```

But but who uses `var` nowadays?

**Secondary**, as for me, I think, that this way is simply confusing for other developers to read. All style guides come from the readability and understandability of code to developers (including you).

It much easier for understanding to see one instantiation for one specific variable. In case above I see two instantiations (no matter that only one will be executed). And what if your code will have long `else if` chain?

**Thirdly**, you need to write less if you instantiate variable outside condition statement, which is good.